# Xcode snippets are not being used in autocomplete

Tags: xcode, autocomplete, code-snippets

I have bolded important information to make this easier to read.

I just **updated** to **Xcode 7.3** yesterday and have tried all day to fix my issue. For class we are **programming in C** and use SVN to modify all of our files to create our project. I **was using Xcode 7.2** to do all of the previous assignments.

My current routine is that **I do not create new projects** for our assignments, **I just open the *.c files** with Xcode. Where my problem comes up is that **when I start typing** for instance **a "For loop"** in the previous version **I get this for autocomplete:**

```
for (initialize; condition; reinitialize){
     statements
}
```

**where I could tab across and edit the place holders with variables/values that I would use in the loop. Now in Xcode 7.3 when I type for all autocomplete shows me is just** [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pAReE.png)
**with no brackets or parenthesis.**

If I drag the snippets to the middle of my code it appears, but that is time consuming and frankly a pain. **I have tried deleting derived data**, but seeing as I don't create a new project for each assignment I don't think this helps me. **I have also tried deleting the cache file and reinstalling the old 7.2 Xcode to no avail.**

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Hit the Tab or Enter key when you see 'for' I think. It auto fills the rest of the stuff for me at least at which point you can Tab more.

EDIT: Don't hit Space key after typing 'for', then the autocomplete suggestions go away. Looks like this in 7.3 (slightly diff. param names than yours).

```
for (initialization; condition; increment) {
    statements
}
```

Comment: Oh, sorry. I knew the parameters didn't look right. Thats what I used to do in the old versions, but now after I hit tab it it just stays for, it doesn't fill in the others just leaves me with 'for'

Comment: Do you even get the autocomplete dropdown? When I type `for`, the first option in the suggestions is `for - For Statement`

Comment: No, all I get is for in the drop down, but it doesn't show for statement which makes me think something got messed up when it updated and reinstalling the old versions did fix it.

Answer (score 0):

I found my solution to why it is not working. In the .c file I was currently working on, the functions where defined like this:

```
int main()
// comments
{
Return
}
```

And when I went to type for in it would not register it as a function, but if I changed where the bracket is to this:

```
int main(){
// comments
Return
}
```

I get code completion like I used to. I am not sure why this is an issue because I swear it was working before.